# jsPDF permitir archivo png cual seria la forma adecuada

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

buen dia,
estoy usando angular 12 y e integrado la libreria jsPDF https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf
todo bien pero necesito usar Imágenes en formato .png pero esta librería no lo permite, buscando hablan de un plugin para dar soporte png

https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/modules_png_support.js.html

pero no se cual es la forma adecuada de integrarlo.
alguien sabe cual es?
gracias

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";




const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'letter');
const width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth()
const options = { background: 'white', scale: 3, };

    let newImg = "midomino.com/url/imagen.png"

    doc.addImage(newImg, "PNG", 0, 0, 276, 216);
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar canvas para convertir la imagen a png. Revisa este ejemplo https://stackblitz.com/edit/jspdf-ayw7vt?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: el asunto es q necesito la imagen con transparencias. la idea es una firma en .png sobre una plantilla.

Comment: La firma tiene que estar sobre el texto?

Comment: mi pensado es tener una imagen jpg que sera el diseño del certificado este tendra sombras y colores y encima de este diseño va la  firma en .png  q viene de una base de datos

Comment: Otra opción es modificar el diseño del certificado para que no te afecte una imagen opaca de la firma, pero si no es posible, toca seguir investigando.

Comment: en la documentación de la librería JsPDF hablan de soporte .png pero no tiendo muy como implementarlo . https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/modules_png_support.js.html

Comment: Creo que el problema es tu implementación. Remplaza en addimage `newImg` por `img`